# how to resolve application class error

Tags: android, livecode

I have created a LiveCode app and now want to turn it into a standalone application for Android.

When tested as a Windows standalone, everything is fine. When I try to create an Android standalone, I get the following error message:

> There was an error while saving the standalone application cannot compile application class.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Down-voters: please stay away from this question if you have no clue whatsoever about the programming language LiveCode. This is a genuine and valid question about compiling an app with LiveCode. If you have a question about compiling an app in Java for instance, we don't down-vote your questions either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following issues may cause this problem:

1. You didn't install the Android SDK
2. You installed the Android SDK but not the packages of version 2.2 of the Android platform
3. You didn't specify the (correct) location of the Android SDK in Livecode's application preferences
4. There is an incompatibility between the Android SDK and files that are included in the standalone or a file is missing
5. Due to a permissions problem, the Android command line tool can't write the .apk file to the destined location

Comment: Point 3 was the problem. Once I went into `Edit>Preference>Mobile Support>Android SDK` and set the location of root SDK to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk the standalone compiled ok